# How is Cartesian differential equation converted into cylindrical differential equation for electron motion in electromagnetic field?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, coordinate-systems

[Source-Page no. 12](https://ecedmans.files.wordpress.com/2014/10/microwave-devices-and-circuits-samuel-liao.pdf)
[image: Equations]

How the cylindrical differential equations are obtained in the figure?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are seeking how to express the temporal derivative and cross product in cylindrical coordinates. These can be be found in [Weisstein, Eric W. "Cylindrical Coordinates." From *MathWorld*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html).